# Daemonize a php file on remote machine

Tags: php

Im trying to spawn beanstalk workers on remote machines from a control server.

I have a function that takes a hostname, SSHes on the private network to the target machine, and then runs commands on that machine.

The command that I use to spawn workers (when I do it manually in prompt on the target server) is:

```
nohup /path/to/php /path/to/file/worker.php &
```

The output from that is:

```
nohup: ignoring input and appending output to `nohup.out'
```

To get back to prompt, it requires a ctrl+c

When I do this from a remote machine the script starts, and it shows output "worker started" which sits there and waits for work. I have to ctrl+c to get back to prompt.

When I run this command with php in the browser, it spawns the worker, but the browser just hangs after, and eventually hits the nginx timeout. I assume this is because shell_exec() which I use to run the command waits for the prompt after it ran the command, but that requires a ctrl+c, so it thinks the command didn't finish executing.

How can I get it to return to prompt after running that command by itself?

Answer (score 1):

You can create dameon in PHP in many ways. There libraries for this,

1. [System_Daemon Pear package](http://pear.php.net/package/System_Daemon)
2. [PHP-Daemon github package](https://github.com/shaneharter/PHP-Daemon)

The idea is quite simple.

- **Fork  a child process and exit the parent**
- **Close all stdin, stdout, stderr and dont ever output anything.**

Comment: Why complicate things with libraries? I need to deploy this to over a 100 servers, and the fewer dependencies I can have the better.

Comment: I've never ventured into CLI territory before, and Im not exactly sure how to do that.

Comment: The basic idea is language independent.